# Create a dynamic dropdown with mysqli based

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, drop-down-menu, mysqli

I'm trying to develop a JS function that creates a new dropdown based on a selection from previous dropdown. Basically a dropdown to select a list of cities based on the selction of state. Anyone have some suggestions?

Here is the javascript I am using :

```
function city() {
var opt = document.getElementById('State');
var sel = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value;
var dropdown = document.getElementById('City');
document.write("<?php mysqli_select_db($GLOBALS['SSDN'],$database_SSDN);     $query_City = 'SELECT * FROM city WHERE State = sel ORDER BY City ASC'; $City = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['SSDN'],$query_City) or die(mysql_error()); while ($row_City = mysqli_fetch_array($City, MYSQL_ASSOC)) ?>");

var o = document.createElement('option');
o.text = document.write("<?php echo $row_City['City'];?>");
o.value = document.write("<?php echo $row_City['City'];?>");
dropdown.options.add(o);
}
```

And here is the html :

```
       <td><select name="State" class="Field" id="State">
      <?php
      while ($row_Recordset1 = mysqli_fetch_array($Recordset1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          ?>
          <option value = "<?php echo $row_Recordset1['State'];?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['State'];?></option>
          <?php
      }
      ?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
    <td><div align="right" class="Label">Select New Rehbar City :</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><select name="City" class="Field" id="City" onfocus="City();">

    </select></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I did something like this with AngularJS. its double data binding feature is handy, but it is a lot of work to learn and setup… see their introduction tutorial to understand how it could help.

Answer (score 0):

i can remember this one from 2011: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/chained-ajax-selects-jquery/

It's called chained select boxes. the link above gives a tutorial on how to implement it. Have a look at it maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client side scripting (programming) language and PHP is a server side programming language, This means you can not run PHP codes when the page is already flushed into client browser and you can only run Javascript codes when the page is already loaded!

These lines has no meaning and will not give you the desired result:

```
document.write("<?php mysqli_select_db($GLOBALS['SSDN'],$database_SSDN);     $query_City = 'SELECT * FROM city WHERE State = sel ORDER BY City ASC'; $City = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['SSDN'],$query_City) or die(mysql_error()); while ($row_City = mysqli_fetch_array($City, MYSQL_ASSOC)) ?>");
o.text = document.write("<?php echo $row_City['City'];?>");
o.value = document.write("<?php echo $row_City['City'];?>");
```

Put your options(data) inside a javascript variable then use them in your script, something like this:

```
<script>
var myOptions = [
    <?php
    // Select and fetch the data from database
    // Loop over your selected data and flush them into your javascript array
    while ($row_City = mysqli_fetch_array($City, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        // if still have data:
        ?>'<?php echo $row_City["field_name"] ?>',<?php
        // else:
        ?>'<?php echo $row_City["field_name"] ?>'<?php
    }
    ?>
];

for (option in myOptions){
    // add each option to your drop down element
}

</script>
```